# Want to return current page limit in response in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-pagination, drf-queryset

Want to return current page limit `current_items_per_page` in response.

- **pagination.py**

```
class CustomPageNumberPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 10 # Number of objects to return in one page
    page_size_query_param = 'total_count'
    max_page_size = 20
    page_query_param = 'page_no'
    page_size_query_param = 'limit_pr_page'

    def generate_response(self, query_set, serializer_obj, request):

        Try:
            page_data = self.paginate_queryset(query_set, request)

        except NotFoundError as e:
            return Response({"response": False, "return_code": "NotFoundError", "result": {}, "message": errors["invalid_page"]},  status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        serialized_page = serializer_obj(page_data, many=True)
        return Response({
        "response": True,
        "return_code": "success",
        "result":serialized_page.data,
        "message": "Success",
        'page_no': self.page.number,
        'current_items_per_page': self."?",
        'max_limit_per_page': self.max_page_size,
        'last_page': self.page.paginator.num_pages,
        'total_items': self.page.paginator.count,
        },
        status=status.HTTP_200_OK
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use len() of current page's object_list:

```
'current_items_per_page': len(self.page.object_list),
```

Comment: I got same output since I was using `'current_items_per_page' : self.page.paginator.per_page,` - `self.get_page_size(request)` both returns the total number of limit we are requesting but want to return the total number of record I'm getting in response.

Comment: @MdHassan413 so you need count of records on current page?

Comment: Yes, It supposes to return the sum of the current page recodes.

Comment: @MdHassan413 Try `self.page.object_list.count()` as well, it should be more efficient.

Comment: facing error while using `self.page.object_list.count()` error is :  `"list.count() takes exactly one argument (0 given)"`